# PHP while loop echoing duplicates

Tags: php, sql-server, while-loop

I need some help with some methodology

I have a SQL statement that fetches results from a `questions` 'header table'.

`while()` the data is being fetched I'm running another SQL statement that pulls `comments` from a 'sub table' according to the `id` fetched from the `questions` table.

When I echo all together, `question` number 1's `comments` show fine, all the comments related to the `question` are showing fine.

The issue is when `question` number 2's `comments` are echoed, comments from `question` number 1 show up (duplicated).

I just can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Here's a simplified version of what my code looks like just to show the methodology:

```
$comment_list = ""; // to display comments
$GET_QUESTIONS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ...");
// parameters are bound here using $GET_STATEMENTS->bindParam();

while($row = $GET_QUESTIONS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $question_id = $row['id'];
    $question_string = $row['string'];

    // NOW I PULL THE COMMENTS
    $GET_COMMENTS = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ...");
    // parameters are bound here using $GET_COMMENTS->bindParam();

    while($row = $GET_COMMENTS->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $comment_id = $row['id'];
        $comment_string = $row['string'];

        $comment_list .= "
            <p>" .$comment_string. "</p>
        ";

    }

    echo "
        <h1>" .$question_string. "</h1>
        " .$comment_list. "

    ";

}
```

Why are the duplicates happening when echoing the second `question`?

Comment: You've to reset the  $comment_list variable before the second while loop. Set it as  $comment_list = null ; just before the second while loop.

Comment: @DareScorp, thanks, that solved it! Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to reset the $comment_list variable before the second while loop.
 Set it as

```
$comment_list = null ;
```

Just before the second while loop. That's all !